# migrating to ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, migration, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a legacy `ASP.NET` application written in .NET 3.5. The application is data intensive - no ORMs, just `ADO.NET`; uses Windows Authentication. The plan is to migrate to `ASP.NET Core` running on Linux.

My question is what roadblocks will I hit when migrating to ASP.NET Core? I realize the presentation portion will be rewritten using MVC pattern. Are there some missing features in `.NET Core`, compared to full .NET Framework?

Comment: Not all the classes are ported (offically by MS)to dot net core which runs on non windows platform. Ex : SmtpClient. There are third party libraries which might fulfill what you want. But it is again up to how much you want.

Comment: Windows Authentication is only available on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

well, the task to migrate can be so hard, you can start with an analysis fo your currente code, I recommended that you use [.NET Portability Analyzer](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1177943e-cfb7-4822-a8a6-e56c7905292b), this tool can help you to review your actual code and test what is not supported in net core.

Answer (score 1):

I'll recommend you to migrate your codes to ASP.NET Core with **Full .NET Framework** first to reduce the costs. .NET Core is going to implement .NET Standards V2.0, after that, your migration to .NET Core will become easier. You can achieve the same architecture, same facilities and same performance improvements with ASP.NET Core with Full .NET Framework, and migration to .NET Core will be the second part of your migration.